# Is it possible to hyperlink JavaScript array elements into an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

This is the code I have done so far. I want to hyperlink the websites so that when the array is outputted as a table in HTML, the websites will be clickable and link to their respective webpages. For some reason, the code in type="text/javascript" is different from the code in language="JavaScript" and I have no idea why. If someone could provide the code for language="JavaScript" that would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr id="tbody">
    <th>Mattress Type</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var table = document.getElementById("table");
var body = document.createElement("tbody");

var beds = new Array(3);
beds[0] = ["Spring Mattress", "King Size", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"];
beds[1] = ["Rest Lumbar Support", "Queen Size", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"];
beds[2] = ["Beauty Rest", "Twin Size", "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"];

table.appendChild(tbody);
beds.forEach(function(items) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.textContent = item;
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  table.appendChild(row);
});
</script>
```

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4.1 and removed in subsequent versions. Just remove it. `type="text/javascript"` is not required, it's the default type for script elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.  You just need to continue adding child elements:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var body = document.createElement("tbody");

// initialize an empty array
var beds = [];

// add bed objects to the array
beds.push({
  type: "Spring Mattress",
  size: "King Size",
  link: "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/spring-air/"
});
beds.push({
  type: "Rest Lumbar Support",
  size: "Queen Size",
  link: "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/beautyrest-lumbar-support"
});
beds.push({
  type: "Beauty Rest",
  size: "Twin Size",
  link: "http://factorymattresstexas.com/specials/simmons-beautyrest/"
});

table.appendChild(tbody);
beds.forEach(function(item) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  // You were previously just dumping the whole array contents in a cell.  Most likely you want to have separate cells for each type of information.
  var type = document.createElement("td");
  type.textContent = item.type;

  var size = document.createElement("td");
  size.textContent = item.size;

  // Create the containing cell to hold the link
  var link_td = document.createElement("td");

  // Create the <a href="...">...</a> element
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.textContent = item.link;
  link.href = item.link

  // Add the link to the cell
  link_td.appendChild(link);

  // Add the cells to the row in the order you'd like to see them in
  row.appendChild(type);
  row.appendChild(size);
  row.appendChild(link);

  table.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr id="tbody">
    <th>Mattress Type</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**:
Your beds array was an array of array of strings.  I switched this to use an array of bed objects.  This allows you to define properties and reference those properties by name instead of by index (ie `item.size` vs `item[1]`).  This is cleaner and will scale better as your codebase grows.  You can extend the bed object with additional properties that you want to display.

Comment: You can reduce the code a bit using `row = tbody.insertRow()` and `cell = row.insertCell()`, which create the elements and appends them in one go. You can even do `tbody.insertRow().insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode('foo'))`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @RobG - agreed.  In this case, I don't want to make too many style modifications to the OP's code. An object would make much more sense here as well (rather than an array for the data items).

Comment: Thank you @axlj and @RobG!! If I want to include more columns in my array before the links should I just create more variables and assign them values of document.createElement("td"); followed by variableName.textContext = item[n];?

Comment: @AndrewC Yes -- In addition, I updated my answer with an example showing how you can use an object instead.

Comment: @axlj Thank you! For some reason the table formatting is not applying to the cells with hyperlinks but the hyperlinks themselves are working. I have one more question regarding images...is it possible to append images within the table? In other words, how would I create another table cell and place an image in each cell in that particular image column?

Comment: The same way the link was constructed: Create a new cell. Create an img element, set the img src, add the img element to the cell, add the cell to the row.  If you're still having trouble with this, I'd take a step back and read up on HTML5, CSS, and javascript before you continue.